# SciPy ODEINT not working with certain differential equations

Tags: python, scipy

I'm new to Python and trying to create basic trajectory plots of a 2D system. This is what I'm working with right now. It plots forward trajectories for a number of points.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def dx_dt(x,t):
  return [x[0]*2, x[1]]

xmin = ymin = -10
xmax = ymax = 10


plt.figure()
plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)
ts = np.linspace(0,1,20)
ic = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 11)
for r in ic:
  for s in ic:
    x0 = [r, s]
    xs = sp.integrate.odeint(dx_dt, x0, ts)
    plt.plot(xs[:,0], xs[:,1], "g")

plt.savefig("flowlines.jpg")
```

The issue that's arising is ODEINT is not working with certain systems, instead saying this half a dozen times

> ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.

and subsequently crashing.

I've been playing around with the specific systems of differential equations, and I think I've found the specific problem that's arising. Something like

```
def dx_dt(x,t):
  return [x[1], x[0]**2+x[1]]
```

works, while

```
def dx_dt(x,t):
  return [x[0], x[1]**2+x[0]]
```

does not. It seems that it does not like any specific initial conditions where x' =f(x,y) if f(x,y) contains anything involving x other than addition and scalar multiplication. It can do anything it wants with y. Hence, the first one runs just fine, but the second one fails, because y' = y^2+x involves a power of y.

I have no idea how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0):

You suspicion about the behavior of the solver depending on the algebraic form of the equations is reasonable. It is likely that the systems for which you are experiencing a problem are ones where the solution "blows up" in finite time.  That is, one or both components go to infinity as t approaches a *finite* value.  This can easily happen when the right-hand side depends on powers of the variables.

A simple one-dimensional system that exhibits this behavior is

```
dx/dt = x**2,   x(0) = x0
```

which has the explicit solution

```
x(t) = x0/(1 - x0*t)
```

You can verify that it solves the differential equation and initial condition, at least in a neighborhood of t=0.  As t → 1/x0 (assuming x0 ≠ 0), the solution diverges to infinity.  For example, here's a plot of the solution with x(0) = 0.5:

[image: plot]

The red vertical dashed line indicates where the solution blows up.

Equations like this violate the mathematical assumptions on which ODE solvers such as `odeint` are based. Solvers will generally fail when they encounter such a point, typically because they vainly try to take smaller and smaller steps to bring down the estimated local error as they approach the point where the solution blows up:

```
In [54]: from scipy.integrate import odeint

In [55]: def sys(x, t):
    ...:     return x**2
    ...: 

In [56]: odeint(sys, 0.5, [0, 2.5])
[...]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py:247:
 ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type).
 Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
  warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning)
Out[56]: 
array([[5.00000000e-01],
       [4.82437777e+08]])
```

The solution is the same as the punch line to the old joke:

```
Patient: Doctor, it hurts when I do this...
Doctor:  Then don't do that!
```